# I want to use a custom font in a picker made by Appcelerator Titanium. Is there anyway to do that?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, picker

I'm developing a mobile app using Appcelerator Titanium. I've changed the textFields font but I couldn't do the same with pickers. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add views and therefore labels to picker rows, but that is iOS only. The `font` property applies to mobile web and Tizen only. The pickerRow is well documented, you can find examples and more [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.PickerRow).

Assuming you have already implemented the custom font, it works like this:

```js
var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow();

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  text: 'Custom Row',
  font: { fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: 'myCustomFont' }
});

row.add(label);
```

If you have not added your custom font yet, the [Titanium custom font guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts) explains it all.

Comment: So, there's no "solution" for Android?